# ID3D11DeviceContext Map/Unmap bottleneck

Tags: directx11, maps

I maintain a small rendering engine that displays models in Direct3D 9. I'm currently migrating this to Direct3D 11, and I've hit a snag in how I display points on the model. Using a sphere mesh, I translate to each point in the local coordinates, and draw the mesh. In Direct3D 9, I was using the fixed function pipeline for the drawing of the mesh. So, I would just change the world matrix for each point and draw the mesh. Obviously in Direct3D 11, I need to use shaders and update constant buffers.

The problem I've run into is the high volume of Map/Unmap calls I need to make so that I can set the constant buffers with the updated world matrix. This is creating a bottleneck and the framerate is slower than the Direct3D 9 implementation. If I remove the Map/Unmap calls, performance is much better, but obviously the meshes are in the wrong spot when I do this.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to be doing this? It seems strange to me that I can't mirror the same performance I got from Direct3D 9. One thing I should note is that this is done in C++/CLI, so there is some marshaling going on, but from what I can tell via benchmarking, that doesn't have anything to do with the slow down.

Here is my code:

```
D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedResource;
HRESULT result;

result = device->UnmanagedContextPointer->Map(d3dBuffer, 0, D3D11_MAP_WRITE_DISCARD, 0, &mappedResource);
Marshal::StructureToPtr(data, IntPtr(mappedResource.pData), false);
device->UnmanagedContextPointer->Unmap(d3dBuffer, 0);
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How many times are you mapping per frame?
I'm not sure what you mean by "how I display points on the model"?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. The software allows users to add "points" to build 3D models. To represent those points visually, I use a sphere mesh. It's around 300 points that it starts to slow down noticeably, so that would be 300 mappings per frame.

Comment: I think the issue here is that you're using the map function for the wrong reasons. I think what you want to look at is mesh instancing.

Comment: Ah, I figured there was probably a better technique for what I was trying to do, but I wasn't sure what I was looking for. I will look into instancing, thanks for the tip!

Comment: @JasonTyler While instancing will work for this case, in the general case of having multiple *different* meshes whose positions you want to update every frame, you still don't want to update each vertex every frame.  Instead, update a constant buffer that will contain a transformation matrix that you'll apply to every vertex in the vertex shader.